# How to change direction of expanding of react-native-dropdown-picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-picker-select

Picker works fine, but when it placed bottom of screen, it suppose to expand items upwards, but still goes down..

I checked to [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker) but couldnt find a way? Is there anyone here how to do it?

screenshot:
[image]

Component:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={[styles.map]}
          loadingEnabled
          initialRegion={initialLocation}
          ref={mapRef}>
          {location && (
            <Marker coordinate={location}>
              <Image
                style={{
                  width: 40,
                  height: 40,
                  margin: 5,
                }}
                source={require('../../assets/icons/marker_icon.png')}
              />
            </Marker>
          )}
          
        </MapView>
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', width: '50%'}}>
          <DropDownPicker
            items={allTowns}
            multiple={true}
            multipleText="%d bölge seçildi."
            min={0}
            max={10}
            defaultValue={country}
            containerStyle={{height: 40}}
            itemStyle={{
              justifyContent: 'center',
              alignItems: 'center',
            }}
            onChangeItem={(item) => alert(item)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

In [the documentation, under Advanced > DropDown Box](https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/dropdown-box) it mentions the props 'dropDownDirection'

To make it go up, you must set it to 'TOP' (case is important)